# what is the best technology to use for a cross browser intro video (needs to support iphone and ie6)

Tags: iphone, flash, html, internet-explorer-6, html5-video

I need to have an intro video for a site which I need to work on all browsers including safari on the iphone and IE6. I am thinking of trying to do flash with a html5 fallback or vice versa.

Has anyone had any experience of attempting this? I need to try and get a **smooth a transition from the video into the content of the website** as possible. Am not sure what limitations exist on the iphone?

I know intro videos aren't well liked but this is a requirement for the site.

EDIT -

One thing I would really like to be able to do is **play video in page on an iphone automatically**, while it is looking like it isn't possible I need to know for sure as I have been told it may be using some combination of canvas and video elements or wrapping the video element in some way. I was sent the following link
http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

Comment: It looks like the mention of IE6 is a very important part of this question, however it is not. HTML5 isn't supported in IE6-8. HTML5 animations aren't supporting in anything less than IE10 (which is still in beta).

Comment: I don't mind using flash on IE for the video, it is more important that I get smooth transitions on all browsers into the content of the site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop and determine what's more important: Supporting a browser that is over a decade old or supporting a platform that is growing rapidly. That's really it. But if you continue on that line of thought, you'll learn quickly that you can't do HTML5 animations in any stable version of IE currently anyways.

So, you have two options. Develop in HTML5 and place alternative text in it's place for all IE visitors or develop in Flash and place alternative text in it's place for all iOS devices. Honestly, doing the same video twice (Flash and HTML5) seems like wasted effort. (Even with Google's new "Swiffy" SWF -> HTML 5 convertor, it's good, but it's not perfect and it doesn't support audio.)

If it was me in your shoes, I'd go with HTML5. IE10 is right around the corner and it supports animations. HTML5 is the new standard and that's the way everything is going. It seems like the logical choice to me.

Comment: Unfortunately will need to support both even if it means doing the work twice. The site will be translated for china so IE6 support is important although can use flash for the video side of this. I am currently trying to find out if it is possible to have a video automatically play in page on the iphone?

Comment: It is not. The iPhone will require a "click". This will cause the iPhone's video player to launch, pushing Safari into the background, to display the video.

Comment: IE8 will be popular for a long time to come. There is no support for IE9 in XP.

Comment: If you're still supporting XP, and software that runs on it, then therein lies your problem. The fact the people feel the need to continue supporting these legacy systems and browsers is what causes these legacy systems to linger. When sites and applications start to omit support for these legacy systems, only then do people start to see the advantages of upgrading away. It's really a catch-22, but I will always be on the forward-thinking side of it.

Comment: My tech director thinks that it is possible to get video playing in page on an iphone by wrapping using canvas tags in some way so going to have to research a bit. I have the following link but doesn't help too much http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/ . I'm wondering whether I should ask another question about this specifically..

Comment: I can answer that for you. You can't. iPhone cripples the ability to play inline video, even in the `<canvas>`. It will always open in the standalone video player.

Comment: Ok, a few other people here agree but needed to make sure, thanks for your help :)